# Handlebars component rendering but not populated with json data

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I am new to ember and I am trying to create a navigation component in my ember.js app.

I have previously created a component the exact same way that renders my blog posts from json data provided by an API. Basically the code you see here is the exact same but the keyword post have been substituted with the keyword page.

The problem is that the handlebars component is being rendered but page.title.rendered is not 'rendered'. Even when I try to console.log(payload) in my serializer, I get no console output. It is as if they are not recognized.

json sample from api

```
[
   {
      "id":139,
      "title":{
         "rendered":"test"
      }
   }
]
```

adapters/page.js

```
export default Eudora.extend({

    pathForType() {
        return 'pages';
    }
});
```

models/page.js

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import DS from 'ember-data';

const { 
    attr,
    //belongsTo 
} = DS;

export default Model.extend({

    title: attr()

});
```

routes/pages.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
    Route,
    set
} = Ember;

export default Route.extend({

    model() {

        return this.store.findAll('page');
    },

    setupController(controller, model) {
        set(controller, 'pages', model);
    }
});
```

serializers/page.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

    normalizeResponse( store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {

        payload = { pages: payload };

        return this._super( store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType );

    }
});
```

templates/components/global-navigation.hbs

```
{{#each pages as |page|}}
    <li>
        <a href="#">{{page.title.rendered}}</a>
    </li>          
{{/each}}
```

templates/application.hbs

```
{{global-navigation pages=pages}}
```

Comment: This may be small enough to make an ember-twiddle. Are you seeing any errors? Why are you using setupController?

Comment: I didn't know there was a tool like that, nice. No errors what so ever.
so that I can call {{#each pages as |page|}} instead of {{#each model as |page|}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kumkanillam for helping me finding the answer. As written in the comments my problem is:

> ...You are including global-navigation in application route but you
>   are loading model in pages route...

Therefor I had to expand my routes/application.js to include both posts and pages. The code bellow illustrates how I did that:

routes/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({

            posts: this.store.findAll('post'),
            pages: this.store.findAll('page')
        });

    },

    setupController(controller, model) {
        Ember.set(controller, 'posts', model.posts);
        Ember.set(controller, 'pages', model.pages);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `content` property in `page` model. correct code would be

```
<a href="#">{{page.title.rendered}}</a>
```

I guess in `adapters/page.js` file,  `Eudora` is extending `DS.RESTAdapter`.

Pages route model hook is returning page model but you are trying to include it in `application.hbs`. so move `{{global-navigation pages=pages}}` to `routes/pages.hbs`. and access URL `'/pages`.

I created sample [EMBER-TWIDDLE](https://ember-twiddle.com/#/8292d3eef94f3a12c7b78402190fe568?openFiles=routes.pages.js%2Ctemplates.components.global-navigation.hbs&route=%2Fpages) for you. which will display the result for both application and pages routes.

Comment: yes, Eudora is extending DS.RESTAdapter and just contain the host endpoint.

It is correct that there is no content property in the page model. That is a typo from my side. I have corrected my question. in fact it does say {{page.title.rendered}} in my code.

Comment: @odinp123 {{page.title.rendered}} is this working ? or still facing the problem ?..

Comment: {{page.title.rendered}} is not working. @kumkanillam

Comment: wait then I will update my twiddle with exact code. let us see it resolves or not.

Comment: @odinp123 problem is - You are including global-navigation in application route but you are loading model in pages route...

Comment: I was actually just going to ask that same question. So do I have change everything related to 'pages' so that it is in the 'application' files or would it be sufficient to just change the route part?

Comment: sufficient to change just routes part. that should work. both ways you can make it work...you can check out my updated twiddle..For URL`/` and `/pages` it will work.

Comment: I have change my route to:

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model() {

        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            posts: this.store.findAll('post'),
            pages: this.store.findAll('page')
    });

        //return this.store.findAll('post');
    },

    setupController(controller, model) {
        this._super(...arguments);
        Ember.set(controller, 'posts', model.posts);
        Ember.set(controller, 'pages', model.pages;
    }
});

But still no luck

Comment: file name of the route ?

Comment: routes/application.js

Comment: I got it now and I will write the answer now